# Primary Decomposition and Invariant Subspace Question

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is from Hoffman & Kunze Section 6.8 on Primary Decomposition, number 10:
Let T be a linear operator on the finite-dimensional space V, let $p = {p_1}^{r_1}\cdots{p_k}^{r_k}$ be the minimal polynomial for T, and let $V = W_1 \oplus\cdots\oplus W_k$ be the primary decomposition for T, i.e., $W_j$ is the null space of $p_j(T)^{r_j}$ . Let W be any subspace of V which is invariant under T. Prove that 
$$  W = (W \cap W_1) \oplus  (W \cap W_2) \oplus \cdots\oplus  (W \cap W_k) $$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the min poly of $T$ restricted to $W$ divides the min poly of $T$, to obtain min poly of $T|w$ as a product of powers of $p_i$'s, but here the powers are less or equal to $r_i$'s. Say the powers are $d_i$'s. Invoke Primary decomposition on W, and try proving ker $p_i(T)^d_i = W \cap W_i$.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/